# How can I resolve force close when default account is NOT available using Google plus login in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. I am using Google plus log in so user can log in using his/her Google account. It's working when default gmail account is available. But I am getting force close when there is no default account. I even added permissions in manifest file.Please help me to resolve my problem.

Thanks,

Prashant.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Google Account first like this ...

```
private boolean deviceHasGoogleAccount(){
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] checkAccount = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        return checkAccount.length >= 1 ? true : false;
}
```

Also add permission to Manifest file like this ..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Hope this helps ...